# Error: Failed to resolve: com .android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[Failed to resolve: com .android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0]
i tried 24.0.0 - 24.1.0 - 24.1.1 and the same error has founded

Here is my gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxxxxx"

        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 8
        versionName "3.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
}
```

i hope to resolve this error

Comment: I think by mistake you have added a space in this line after **com** `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`

Comment: was that space in your main code also? if so then remove that and sync gradle again

Comment: @KalyaniAmrutkar yeah thx

Answer (score 1):

You have a space after com. Remove the space and rebuild project. If that doesn't work,  check your **SDK manager** and see if those versions exist there. If they do, download the one you want. If already installed, remove and reinstall the package and do a **Clean Build**.

Answer (score 1):

I think by mistake you have added a space in this line after word **com** :

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`

You just remove that space as I did in above line and sync your `gradle` again.